# android studio build The resource name must start with a letter

Tags: android

When I trying to build the apk, the error showing me. But I[image] cant solve it. please help me.

```
app/build/generated/res/resValues/pixol/debug/values/gradleResValues.xml
```

Error
The resource name must start with a letter

[image: Error Image]

Comment: In your xml file (line number 7) you can't use number for the name attribute.

Comment: Please post the error log as text, not as an image.

Comment: Have you looked at all your resources yet to see what doesn't start with a letter?

Answer (score 0):

In your gradleResValue.xml file there is a resource name which is starting with either a number or special character. So try to find the resource name and rename it with proper naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at string.xml

```
<string name="468108487144248" translatable="false"></string>
```

Here resource name must be start with letter

You can use like

```
<string name="a468108487144248" translatable="false"></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, your resource name must start with a letter. Your resource name starts with *name="468...."*
Change the name so it DOES start with a letter, do NOT change it in the the xml but where the name originates.

Answer (score 0):

Your string name should start with a letter
Line number 7, try always using a string to name a variable, at worst cases try at least starting the name with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Ths issue is in your facebook app id on line number `30` in `app/build.gradle` file.

just replace the line

```
resValue "string", "468108487144248", ""
```

with

```
resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "468108487144248"
```